# How do i change the order of integration in this question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having lot of trouble in changing order of integration .Can someone please help ?
By doing some work i got answer 0.125 .But not sure about what is right order change. Thanks.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{y}{\sin y} \text{ if } y\neq 0\\
1 \text{ if } y=0
\end{cases}$

Then the integral

$$\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=\sin^{-1} x}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}f(x,y)\mathop{dy}\mathop{dx}$$

correct up to three decimal places is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch the region.  For each $x \in [0,1]$, $y \in [\sin^{-1} x, \pi/2]$.  So sketch the curves $y = \pi/2$, and $y = \sin^{-1} x$ for $0 \le x \le 1$.  Equivalently, the second curve can be written $x = \sin y$.

Now, for these two curves, shade in the region of integration.  Now if we interchange the order of integration, first consider the range of $y$ for this region.  For each such $y$-value, what is the range of $x$?

Comment: range of x - from 0 to siny

Comment: range of y is from 0 to pi/2

Comment: Correct!  So, what is the value of your integral?

Comment: 0.125 .is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch the region on google or something. x ranges from 0 to sin(y). y ranges from 0 to Pi/2